# Add test package to existing Android Studio project

Tags: android, testing, android-studio, junit, package

I have an existing android app and I'm trying to implement some junit tests. Normally (with Android Studio 1.2) the test package is created automatically. If I try to manually create folders to mimic the structure I've seen elsewhere there is either no option to create package under those folders, or I can't name it what I should be able to without it being placed under the existing package. Anyone know how to properly add this just as it would have been when auto created?

Every article covering this assumes its already there... like this one:
http://evgenii.com/blog/testing-activity-in-android-studio-tutorial-part-1/

[image: missing test package]

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way to do this, but I just created a new project, let it auto-generate the test package, and moved everything from my old project into the new one. There were a few references after the refactoring that needed to be cleaned up but it worked quite well for the most part.